# No $k$-critical graph has exactly $k + 1$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Can anyone help with this?

> Deduce that no $k$-critical graph has exactly $k {+} 1$ vertices.

---

A $k$-critical graph is a critical graph with chromatic number $k$. A critical graph is a graph in which every vertex or edge is a critical element. A vertex or an edge is a critical element of a graph $G$ if its deletion would decrease the chromatic number of $G$.

Comment: Do you have a definition of "$k$-critical"?

Comment: A critical graph is a graph in which every vertex or edge is a critical element. A k-critical graph is a critical graph with chromatic number k. A vertex or an edge is a critical element of a graph G if its deletion would decrease the chromatic number of G, but such decrement can be no more than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Such a graph would, if it existed, be $k$-colorable, so imagine that it *has* been $k$-colored -- that is, $k-1$ vertices each have a color of their own and the last $2$ vertices have the same color.

Divide into cases depending on whether one, both, or neither of the two same-colored vertices has all the single-color vertices as neighbors. Show that each of these assumptions leads to a contradiction.